# angularjs JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, scope

I have the following function

```
 $scope.makeBasic = function (item, node1, node2, node3) {

  var rabbitHole = $scope[dbTable][node1][node2][node3];
  ...
}
```

in the html i call it like this

```
ng-change="makeBasic(item, 'contactData', 'emails', 'data')"
```

dbTable = "people" which comes from a different var and is working ok.

the end goal for the $scope is this:

```
$scope.people.contactData.emails.data
```

I can construct the scope fine with the `rabbitHole` variable but that restricts me to only to the 3 variables node1, node2, node3

I am trying to get to the desired $scope with this:

```
ng-change="makeBasic(item,'contactData.emails.data')"  

 $scope.makeBasic = function (item, sample) {

var rabbitHole = $scope[dbTable][sample];
 ...
}
```

but is not working and is undefined.

this way what ever i put in the var sample `('contactData.emails')` or `('contactData.emails.data...')` etc the $scope can be constructed accordingly

does anyone know what's the solution?

Comment: not exactly sure what your expected is but, if you want a xpath with the content made from arguments you can do $scope.rabbitHole = [dbTable][node1][node2][node3]; now this path is exposed to the view for use.

Comment: i want to avoid [node1][node2][node3], and just have[sample], which will include the arguments. does that make sense

Comment: you might have to do string manipulation splice and join at the '.', alternatively i suggest using [lodash-get method](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#get). you could even look at the source code to see how they implement this that way you wouldn't have to add this utility lib.